# Unable to authenticate a SOAP service using node.js

Tags: ajax, node.js, soap

I am trying to authenticate SOAP service via node.js (node-soap/ws.js) modules. I also tried using ajax call. But I did not find any success. 
Any help regarding this would be appreciated.